# Problem with App developed by Flutter, audio doesn't work for Sumsung Galaxy Note9

Tags: flutter, audio

I use audioplayer to play sound. In other phones it does work but not for the Galaxy Note 9. My app is flutter app.  I tried another app with Galaxy note 9, it is work..no problem with audio sound. 
Don't know how to fix it. 
Thanks in advance for your information.

Comment: What is audioplayer? Is this a code question? If so, please post code.

Answer (score 0):

I played audio from network by Image.network(). And this is solved by setting usesCleartextTraffic = "true".

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. I solved by using mp3 files. It doesn't work with .m4a.